# How to read an external properties file in Maven

Tags: java, build, maven-2, properties-file

Does anyone know how to read a x.properties file in Maven. I know there are ways to use resource filtering to read a properties file and set values from that, but I want a way in my pom.xml like:

```
<properties file="x.properties"> 

</properties>
```

There was some discussion about this:
[Maven External Properties](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg70112.html)

Comment: If you have only a few values, and different users will need different values, consider instead [putting the value in your `settings.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/examples/injecting-properties-via-settings.html).

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Try the 
[Properties Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/)

Comment: I think that's what I'm looking for I couldn't find the 1.0-SNAPSHOT in the maven repositories but there is a release:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/properties-maven-plugin


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Current link: http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/read-project-properties-mojo.html

Comment: Current version:

<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0-alpha-2-SNAPSHOT</version>

from http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/

Comment: The link in the Answer has been updated to the new link from @JesseGlick

Comment: I had problems with this plugin on Windows. If someone has problems too, try out [kuali](http://site.kuali.org/maven/plugins/properties-maven-plugin/1.1.9/index.html) instead.

Comment: The [Kuali](http://site.kuali.org/maven/plugins/properties-maven-plugin/1.1.9/index.html) plugin has the added benefit of being able to read a property file from a jar (classpath) which was necessary in my case.

Comment: The link is now dead.

Answer (score 66):

Using the suggested Maven properties plugin I was able to read in a buildNumber.properties file that I use to version my builds.

```
  <build>    
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
                <file>${basedir}/../project-parent/buildNumber.properties</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
```

Comment: could you show the inside of the buildNumber.properties file? thank you!

Comment: Thanks for a working example. However, why I got an error of `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-1:read-project-properties (execution: default, phase: initialize)`

Comment: When I enter this <plugin> section under <plugins> after </build> and before the regular maven plugins, I am getting this error:
`Plugin 'execution' not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-1:read-project-properties (execution: default, phase: initialize)`

Comment: @BorisBrodski could you show the inside of the buildNumber.properties file? It seems you deleted some details.

Comment: @MoustafaMahmoud why me? That's not my answer :) But I may speculate, that it could look like 'my.great.product.version=1.0.0'.

Comment: As I saw you was discussing something inthe comments. I thought you added some more information. My problem seems when I tried to read the value from the properties file and run the install I didn't get the properties value. So, I wounder if anyone can help to add full example for @Dougnukem's answer

Comment: As I recall the lifecycle configuration issue is a problem specific to Eclipse that requires a mapping in m2e.

Comment: Depending on the used packaging you might need to use the validate phase instead of initialize phase.

Comment: Or even better use <file>${maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory}/buildNumber.properties</file> with current Maven version (but in that case the parent module should have ".mvn" directory present).

Comment: What about to retrieve the file data inside a Java Class???

Answer (score 6):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231561/how-to-share-common-properties-among-several-maven-projects/1265428#1265428) to a similar question describes how to extend the properties plugin so it can use a remote descriptor for the properties file. The descriptor is basically a jar artifact containing a properties file (the properties file is included under src/main/resources).

The descriptor is added as a dependency to the extended properties plugin so it is on the plugin's classpath. The plugin will search the classpath for the properties file, read the file''s contents into a Properties instance, and apply those properties to the project's configuration so they can be used elsewhere.