# User and project specific settings in Maven

Tags: configuration, properties, maven, branch, settings

We develop multiple branches of a project concurrently.  Each developer has multiple working copies, each working copy uses its own DB schema.  (There will typically be a working copy per branch, but sometimes even more than one working copy per branch.)  We need to let Maven know the DB credentials (for the db-migration plugin, for unit tests, for the dev instance of the servlet).

We can't put the credentials in the `pom.xml` because each developer might use different DB schema names.  We can't put the credentials in `settings.xml` because each developer uses more than one schema.

Where do we put the credentials?

For example, http://code.google.com/p/c5-db-migration/ describes that the DB credentials need to be present in `pom.xml` but I would like to externalize them out to a file that's not under revision control.

Answer (score 2):

You could put them into a properties file inside the project directory but which is excluded from source control.

With Maven it's possible to read properties from an external file by using a `<build><filters><filter>` element [as instructed here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_filter_resource_files).

Comment: That's what I want!  But how to tell Maven to read the properties file?  I searched and searched but couldn't find it.  Thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: I don't know either that how to read properties files with Maven. Since it's Maven, probably there is a plugin for it. ;) With Maven 2 it was possible to use a per-project profiles.xml file, but Maven 3 has removed support for it.

Comment: I just found out how to read external properties files with Maven. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I've attempted to clarify the original question by adding an example.  As I understand the `<build><filters><filter>` documentation, it's not possible to use the properties read from an external file in a pom, it's only possible to put them into another external file.

Answer (score 2):

Read following answers:

- [How to read an external properties file in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849389/how-to-read-an-external-properties-file-in-maven)
- [Reading properties file from Maven POM file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144620/reading-properties-file-from-maven-pom-file)
- [Read a file into a Maven property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335221/read-a-file-into-a-maven-property)

or just:

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <configuration>
            <files>
              <file>dev.properties</file> <======== IT IS!!!!!
            </files>
          </configuration>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```