# How to read application.properties from POM.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm not able to find out if it is possible to read any data in Spring's application.properties in the pom.xml file.

In my **application-dev.properties** file, I have an attribute:

```
google.project.id = 123456789
```

In my **application-test.properties** file, I have an attribute:

```
google.project.id = 987654321
```

In my **application.properties** file, I have an attribute. At one point I set it up for **DEV** at another time for **TEST**:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

In my **pom.xml** file, I would like to read this project id according to the configuration in the spring.profiles.active attribute:

```
<configuration>
  <projectId> PROJECT ID ???</projectId>
  <version>1</version>
</configuration>
```

Please, could someone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: This might be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144620/reading-properties-file-from-maven-pom-file

Comment: Hello Gryphon. Yes, I know that. My question is whether it is possible to do otherwise? In the POM.xml file read a property that is in the APPLICATION.PROPERTIES file. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I think prior to your edit you only mentioned the single file (application.properties) to read from, which seems to match usage of the properties-maven-plugin specification in the aforementioned link - e.g. https://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/ However, with reading particular files based on information present in a tertiary file, that may be outside the scope of that plugin.

Comment: Please refer :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703499/using-maven-properties-in-application-properties-in-spring-boot

Comment: @ThiagodeMeloFontana the answer for your question is one post that Dinesh Dontha send the to you.

Answer (score 2):

POM.xml is part of maven project build and has nothing to do with spring.

Spring framework has no idea about pom file.

Comment: Hello Vlad. I understand but I know that it is possible to read a property present in the POM.xml file from APPLICATION.PROPERTIES. My question is whether it would be possible to do contrary to what is in this article: https://medium.com/@derrya/maven-profile-spring-boot-properties-a34f2b2bb386

Comment: I am not aware of the solution that let you populate pom properties from application.properties file. You probably can use environmental variables to set the same value in pom and  application.properties

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to make pom.xml read properties from application.properties, it's possible to do the reverse: **use properties defined in pom.xml within your application.properties or application.yml in Spring Boot**. This can be especially useful for maintaining consistency in project metadata like version, name, etc.

Here's how you can achieve this:

Define the required properties in your pom.xml file:

Be mindful of the ellipsis (...), as it simply indicates that I'm omitting some less relevant information for this context.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" ...>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>the-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>The Name You Defined</name>
    <description>The Description You Want</description>
    ...
</project>
```

Reference these properties in your application.properties or application.yml file:

Below is an example using application.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: "@project.name@"
    version: "@project.version@"
    description: "@project.description@"
    groupId: "@project.groupId@"
    artifactId: "@project.artifactId@"
```

Access these properties in your application code:

You can now use these properties anywhere in your code. For example:

```
public class MyClass {
    
    @Value("${spring.application.version}")
    private String codeVersion;

    // ... other methods and fields ...
}
```

This approach allows you to dynamically insert Maven project information into your Spring Boot application's properties, ensuring that your application's metadata remains consistent with your Maven configuration.