# Read custom version config property from a property file and access it in pom.xml

Tags: maven

I am working with maven projects . I want to read my version number from a property file and access this version variable into my pom.xml instead of updating each time in the 17.3-SNAPSHOT in the pom.xml . So when i  want to update my version in a particular development sprint,the change should have only in the version number property in the property file and will be able to build jar file with the updated version . So I want to create a version config variable in an external property file
 (example : /main/resources/version_config.properties) and access this in pom.xml for the build process .

```
<dependency>
<group Id>x.x.x</group Id>
<artifact Id>maven-model</artifact Id>
<version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of using the above version value(2.0) between version tag , i want to get this value from a property file names xxx.properties (property like , version.config.value=2.0)
 I tried the above solutions .Can any one help on on this ?

Comment: What is the advantage of having an external file which contains the versions of dependencies which should be handled by using a dependencyManagement block in an appropriate parent pom...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maven - read version number from property file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541332/maven-read-version-number-from-property-file)

Comment: For every time .we don't need to change the pom file . We need to change the particular updated property file instead of this .

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to define the version of your application in a specific Maven project that you can use as parent Maven project.

From [Maven documentation "Introduction to the POM" (Example 5)](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) :

> **Example 5**
>
> *The Scenario*
>
> Given the previous original artifact POMs again,
>
> com.mycompany.app:my-app:1's POM
>
> ```
> <project>
>   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>   <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
>   <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
>   <version>1</version>
> </project>
> ```
>
> com.mycompany.app:my-module:1's POM
>
> ```
> <project>
>   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>   <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
>   <artifactId>my-module</artifactId>
>   <version>1</version>
> </project>
> ```
>
> and this directory structure
>
> ```
> .
>  |-- my-module
>  |   `-- pom.xml
>  `-- parent
>      `-- pom.xml
> ```
>
> **The Solution**
>
> To do both project inheritance and aggregation, you only have to apply
>   all three rules.
>
> com.mycompany.app:my-app:1's POM
>
> ```
> <project>
>   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>   <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
>   <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
>   <version>1</version>
>   <packaging>pom</packaging>
>
>   <modules>
>     <module>../my-module</module>
>   </modules>
> </project>
> ```
>
> com.mycompany.app:my-module:1's POM
>
> ```
> <project>
>   <parent>
>     <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
>     <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
>     <version>1</version>
>     <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
>   </parent>
>   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>   <artifactId>my-module</artifactId>
> </project>
> ```
>
> **NOTE:** Profile inheritance the same inheritance strategy as used for the POM itself.

Comment: This is an excellent solution . But my requirement is to create a version config property in a porpetry file and access this in to my pom.xml

Comment: Is there any other solution to access my version property from an external property file into my pom.xml ?