# Read a file into a Maven property

Tags: maven

Is it possible to read a file and store the entire contents into a Maven property?

I'm trying to generate some custom JavaDocs, and they have an option to set a header, but it has to be a string, not a file name (for some reason). I obviously don't want to put a bunch of HTML into my pom.xml, so I need a way to read my `header.html` as a Maven property.

Is this possible? I'm not able to find a standard way, but it seems like a Maven plugin might do this.

Apparently [Ant has what I want](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html), but I'd prefer something lighter weight than the Ant task.

Comment: Brendan, did the solution work? I haven't had a chance to try it myself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849389/how-to-read-an-external-properties-file-in-maven) question on SO. And here is the [properties-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/).

If you'd like not to use *.properties* file, than I can suggest to use the Groovy plugin and a small script that I've written:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>execute</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <properties>
          <header_file>header.html</header_file>
        </properties>
        <source>
          def file = new File(project.properties.header_file)
          project.properties.header_content = file.getText()
        </source>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

After execution of this plugin, you should be able to refer to `${header_content}` property that contains `header.html` file contents.

Comment: this doesnt work if you need to read the property in the pom file