# Maven plugin output to recourse file using filtering

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

I have resource file containing:

```
${project.version}
${dependency.tree}
```

Is it possible to replace (filtering) `${dependency.tree}` property with `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=com.foo.bar` command output ?

Answer (score 1):

No easy way out here, but I think it's possible.

I'd do it this way:

1. Bind `dependency` plugin goal `tree` execution to `generate-resources` phase and configure it to output everything to some file (`outputFile` option, see [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html)).
2. Use `gmaven` plugin to load this file into a `dependency.tree` property (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335221/read-a-file-into-a-maven-property/9339405#9339405) on how to do it). This should go after the previous step in pom.xml and be bound to `generate-resources` phase.
3. Use `resources` plugin + filtering to achieve the goal.

Comment: Thank You. 
I used solution 1. It's a little bit easier to parse then 3., but both works fine for me