# dependency:build-classpath to assembly plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin

Is it possible to build a class path string with dependency:build-classpath  and pass it somehow to assembly plugin so that it can be used to substitute a variable in filtered files?

Best regards, Eugene.

Comment: Yes, but why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I need to produce zip containing shell script which runs soapui (mocks). The jars are to be bundled in same zip.  So I want to have   classpath generated and inserted into this script automatically.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13718970/966590) as an example.