# Create test directory only with test libraries

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm facing this problem:

I'm creating assembly for our customer. In this assembly i want basically 2 important directories:

- `lib/` with all runtime scope project dependencies (transitive included)
- `test/` with all test scope dependencies (transitive included), but without those already present in lib folder

So far i ended up with this assembly file (i included only important parts) :

```
<assembly>
  <id>zip-with-lib-and-test</id>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
        <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
        <useTransitiveFiltering>true</useTransitiveFiltering>
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
    </dependencySet>

    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>test</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
        <includes>
           <include>group:test-artifact1</include>
           <include>group:test-artifact1</include>
        </includes>
        <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

With this i have test dir with named artifacts, but there are no transitive dependencies for those test artifacts.

I need to do exclusion like this: if you are present in lib artifact, you won't be in test.
I tried to do this with maven-dependency-plugin with no luck.

Exact list of dependencies isn't option here, because this assembly will be on multiple artifacts.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to accomplish this task solely by means of assembly plugin. I'd keep what you have now and add another step which would post-process the results of assembly based on your requirements.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov Thank you for your comment, could you please draw in little bit more details, what do you think by "another sptep which would post-precess the results"?

Answer (score 0):

Assembly plugin creates a zip archive (it can also create a directory as an output, but it's cumbersome), so I'd leave it for the final step.

1. Declare two properties for the location of runtime and test dependencies of your project (for example, `runtime.dir` and `test.dir`).
2. Add two executions of maven dependency plugin with phase `prepare-package`: one for runtime dependencies (`includeScope` option should be used) with `runtime.dir` as output directory, another one for test dependencies with `test.dir` as output directory. As a result, you should have runtime + compile depedencies in `runtime.dir` and runtime + compile + provided + test (and system, if you happen to have any) in `test.dir`.
3. Now it's time to add a bit of groovy scripting :) Your script should list all files in `test.dir` and for each of them check if such file exists in `runtime.dir`; if it does, remove this file from `test.dir`. As an example of working with groovy scripts in maven, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9339405/966590).
4. Use assembly plugin to pack everything into zip archive.