# Maven: profile-based properties used in plugins section

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-profiles

I would like to mention I am relatively new in Maven configurations.

My situation:

- I use Maven 3.0.5 to build J2E application
- the application is deployed in four different environments: local, dev, test and prod
- I use maven profiles to configure environment-specific configurations
- I have defined these configurations in `properties` files in the file system.

This is the file system for those:

```
<my-project-root>
---profiles
------local
---------app.properties
------dev
---------app.properties
------test
---------app.properties
```

I load the corresponding property file with the following logic in my `pom.xml`:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <!-- The development profile is active by default -->
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>local</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>prod</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>test</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <finalName>MyProject</finalName>
    <plugins>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>profiles/${build.profile.id}</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

With this configuration I can use the respective properties for my current profile almost everywhere. Everywhere, but the `<plugins>` section. I would pretty much like to load e.g, my database url or credentials from such properties files, but if I include them in the `app.properties` they are not evaluated in the plugins section (e.g. I get value of `${endpoint}` as database endpoint).

**How do I get the properties loaded from files for the profile accessible in the `<plugins>` section?**

PS: Yes, if I add those properties directly in the `pom.xml` as properties under `<profiles>` tag, they are accessible, but I would rather keep my passwords off the pom.

Comment: If putting passwords into `pom.xml` is the only obstacle, swap them with paths to password files (or just file names relative to some known location to lessen leak).

Comment: @VictorSorokin plausible. Still I am looking for neatest possible solution. If I place them in files, then i need the logic to read them somewhere, right?

Comment: If I've got task right, `maven-resources-plugin` will allow you to put per-profile property values into template file which is processed later on: http://portofino.manydesigns.com/en/docs/portofino3/tutorials/using-maven-profiles-and-resource-filtering

Comment: @VictorSorokin I don't believe you have understood me correctly, because with the approach you link to, I have to store the password in the `pom.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do what I wanted to do. I used `properties-maven-plugin` linked from, say [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/880009/1108032).

What I did was the following:

- I added the `properties-maven-plugin` to read the files I needed loaded

  ```
  <plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <phase>initialize</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <files>
             <file>profiles/${build.profile.id}/app.properties</file>
           </files>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
  ```

  Regretfully, here I was not able to make the plugin read all property files in a directory, but I find this good enough.
- I also needed  to remove the error the plugin definition above gave for me in Eclipse (`Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration`). To do thatI followed the instructions from the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14809920/1108032).

With those steps the properties I needed became available for the plugins, that used them.

Note: actually the properties get loaded after the `compile` maven command, but this is good enough for me, as all my property-dependant  goals are to be executed after `compile` goal in sequence of goal calls in all my cases.