# How to define a Maven artifactId in a external property file

Tags: maven

I'm trying to integrate maven in a legacy build setup. The artifactId and version is defined in an external file *build.properties* used by the legacy setup

```
project.name = "foobar"
project.version = "1.0"
```

Basically what I want to do is to define my Maven artifactId and version based on the property variables

```
<artifactId>${project.name}</artifactId>
<version>${project.version}</version>
```

How do I accomplish this in Maven ?

Comment: That will simply not work and it does not really makes sense...simply put it into the pom file where it belongs...

Comment: For this use-case it does. Putting it in the pom would mean that the artifactid and version number would live at two places in the pom and in the property file. In this case Maven doesn't manage the build, it only uses a jar artifact from an Ant task. The reason to integrate Maven is to ease the use and deployment of legacy libraries in Maven based projects. Going all Maven is not an option.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849389/how-to-read-an-external-properties-file-in-maven