# How to reuse properties from application.properties (Spring Boot) in Maven pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, flyway

I would like to define database `url, username, password` in one place. Currently I have

`application.properties` with

```
spring.datasource.url=....
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=00
```

And `pom.xml` with

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <url>....</url>
      <user>sa</user>
      <password>00</password>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

So probably I need to **reuse property values defined in `application.properties`**.

This `<password>${spring.datasource.password}</password>` doesn't work. 
Also I tried

```
 <systemProperties>
    <systemProperty>
      <name>url</name>
      <value>....</value>
    </systemProperty>
    ...
 </systemProperties>
```

Neither approach is working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read an external properties file in Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849389/how-to-read-an-external-properties-file-in-maven)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the reverse by building a properties file from your pom file. In your properties file you'd use something like:

```
password=${pom.password}
```

And your pom file would have something like:

```
<password>your_db_password</password>
```

Then at:

```
mvn clean package
```

Maven will build your properties file.

Here's a simple tutorial: [Add Maven Build Information ...](http://memorynotfound.com/maven-build-information-properties-file/)

Answer (score 0):

As the top two answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849389/how-to-read-an-external-properties-file-in-maven) question (as suggested in rmlan's comment) suggest, use the [properties-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <files>
                    <file>${basedir}/src/main/resources/application.properties</file>
                </files>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then with your `application.properties` do the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>${spring.datasource.url}</url>
        <user>${spring.datasource.username}</user>
        <password>${spring.datasource.password}</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```