# Running sonar analysis with mvn sonar:sonar ignores sonar-project.properties

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

Latest 3.3 sonar-maven-plugin and 5.6 LTS as web server.
Running sonar analysis with `mvn sonar:sonar` 
( [Scanner for Maven](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven) )
ignores `sonar-project.properties` file. (with many parameters https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters)

Is it that the expected behavior?
So do I have to configure all sonar parameters within `pom.xml` files?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Other way would be to configure reading via [Maven Properties Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/)

[Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849389/how-to-read-an-external-properties-file-in-maven)

```
   <build>    
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
                <file>sonar-project.properties</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Any way to get this to fire with `mvn sonar:sonar`? For me this works only if you run something like `mvn verify sonar:sonar`

Comment: Try `mvn properties:read-project-properties sonar:sonar`

See https://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/

Comment: I don't know if this every got working and see this as acceptable answer, but the official documentation  says that it is not possible and I quote In general, any of these parameters can be configured just like any other maven property (in order of override priority):

On the mvn command line where the scanner goal is invoked, using the -D argument prefix.
In the pom.xml file of the project. Unlike the plain-vanilla SonaScanner CLI, the SonarScanner for Maven uses the pom.xml instead of the sonar-project.properties file.
In the global settings.xml.

Answer (score 31):

That is correct: the scanner for Maven ignores the `sonar-project.properties` file.

To pass analysis parameters when using the scanner for Maven,
set them as `<properties>` in the `pom.xml`, for example:

```
<properties>
    <sonar.host.url>http://yourserver</sonar.host.url>
</properties>
```

Or, you could also pass parameters using `-D` on the command line, for example:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://yourserver
```

Answer (score 0):

From this documentation [Sonar Scanner For Maven](https://docs.sonarcloud.io/advanced-setup/ci-based-analysis/sonarscanner-for-maven/), it doesn't appear that Maven Sonar Scanner uses the sonar-project.properties. sonar-scanner CLI on the other hand does. So, I went with installing the sonar-scanner CLI