# Change maven-shade-plugin outputFile from command line

Tags: java, maven

I am using the maven-shade-plugin in my pom.xml and I want to be able to dynamically set the `<outputFile />` from the command line, something like this:

```
mvn -outputFile=C:/Users/Oscar/Desktop/MyJar.jar
```

I don't want to hardcode a filepath directly in the pom.xml because I don't want it in the repo. On our production server, I want to be able to specify an **output path** for the shaded jar and on my local development machine I want to be able to specify my own path.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <relocations>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>com.zaxxer.hikari</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>io.github.hornta.lib.hikari</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>com.google.gson</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>io.github.hornta.lib.gson</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>org.slf4j</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>io.github.hornta.lib.slf4j</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>org.flywaydb.core</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>io.github.hornta.lib.flywaydb</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                </relocations>
                <outputFile>I NEED TO SET THIS PATH FROM COMMAND LINE (not having it in the repo)</outputFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: You can do that with profiles (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).  Essentially you would put the "project default" version in the pom, and then each developer enables a profile that overrides that value for local work.  Other answers based on property plugin or system properties also would work -- best choice depends on your specific situation.

Comment: What if I want my "project default" to be nothing? If I dont specify anything, I don't event want the <outputFile> to be in my pom.xml.

Comment: Then don't include `<outputFile>` in the pom at all.  If that element is mandatory, it may refuse to build without an enabled profile that includes it.  Worst case you set it to the plugin default (try `maven help:effective-pom` to see the verbose version of the project pom)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a system property to define the value of `outputFile`

Change the line in your `pom.xml`

```
<outputFile>${outputFilePath}</outputFile>
```

And then use the variable in command line

```
mvn -DoutputFilePath=C:/Users/Oscar/Desktop/MyJar.jar ...
```

You can define the default value in the `properties` of your `pom.xml`

```
<properties>
    <outputFilePath>C:/Users/Oscar/Desktop/Default/MyJar.jar</outputFilePath>
</properties>
```

Comment: If I don't specify -DoutputFilePath, can I have to so it builds to the default location? Because default it builds into /target directory

Comment: you can define a default value in the properties tag

Comment: @Doodlemeat you can also use the variables already provided by maven for the default path like `${project.build.directory}` or `${project.basedir}`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a properties file to set the value, and then add the properties file to your `.gitignore`. This is actually a pretty common use case, as values like this will vary across deployment environments. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849389/how-to-read-an-external-properties-file-in-maven)  or [this article](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2078520/open-source-tools/develop-an-environment-aware-maven-build-process.html) for discussion around the issue.

Comment: Is it possible to add some logic like if I don't specify a property, it will default to its normal location which in my case is /target?