# Use content of an external file as the version value in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I would like to have an external file, containing a single value - a version, such as `1.0`
Then, I would like to reference this in my pom.xml, such that the `version` property will be set during build by the value I give to it
This way I can have proper versioning on my jar without commiting changes using mvn to the entire reactor every time
For example, something like:

```
<version>./version.txt</version>
```

And if the content of `version.txt` is `1.0`, when I compile my code to a jar, mvn will evaluate the content of my file and set the jar version to `1.0`

It slightly differs from properties file since my external file is not a `key=value` formatted file, its merely a value which I want to read in full and have it represent the value of a key in my `pom.xml`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read an external properties file in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849389/how-to-read-an-external-properties-file-in-maven)

Comment: Ill check. I didnt realize properties refer to anything, I thought its something specific

Comment: Personally, I would not recommend this. This would mean that if you forgot to update that file after making a release, you 're in for a surprise afterwards.

Comment: I agree in general @Stultuske but its a current flow I need to adapt myself into. And this file is a central location that specifies the version for the release of the entire software suite, so its actually fine (for this particular case, anyway)

Comment: I recommend to read this: https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by running the [maven versions](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) plugin before running your build

Your build script could loook something like this:

```
mvn -B -DnewVersion=$(cat ./version.txt) -DgenerateBackupPoms=false versions:set
mvn -B clean install
```