# Moving dependencies from pom to properties file

Tags: java, maven

is there any way to moving dependencies from **pom.xml** to **application.properties** file?

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

somehow move to **src/main/resources/application.properties**?

[image]

Comment: what is the use case of it?

Comment: @tuhin47
 im on trainee and mentor write in pull request to move dependencies to properties

Comment: What you are asking for and saying makes no sense. You need to explain much better what you are trying to do and why.

Comment: @RoToRa i have a very strange mentor, he can not to answer for my questions for the whole day... i'd love to explayne, but i dont understand what he want from me

Comment: @стасевич Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: @стасевич You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849389/how-to-read-an-external-properties-file-in-maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mentor is not asking you to move the dependencies to the file `application.properties`, but to move the dependency versions to the [`<properties>` section](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) of the maven file (`pom.xml`).

Example:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And then in the `<properties>` section:

```
<properties>
  <postgresql.version>42.3.3</postgresql.version>
</properties>
```